# Determining whether the graph of a function has a tangent at the origin

Tags: calculus

This question was in chapter 2 of my calculus book.

Determine whether the function has a tangent at the origin.  Explain your answer.
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 sin\frac1x, & x\neq 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
[image: question #41 from my textbook]

I have not learned derivatives yet and I am not sure how to approach this problem. The answer key mentioned the Squeeze theorem determines that the limit = 0.

If anyone could walk me through this problem, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin(1/h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin\frac{1}{h}$$
where the $\sin\frac{1}{h}$ is bounded and get the limit $0$.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your question is less so about the function in the book and moreso about how to use the Squeeze theorem to determine whether a function has a tangent line at a point or not.

The Squeeze Theorem (as stated on Wolfram mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SqueezingTheorem.html)

> Let there be two functions $f_-(x)$ and $f_+(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is "squeezed" between the two, $$f_-(x)\leq f(x)\leq f_+(x).$$
>   If $$r=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_-(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_+(x)$$ 
>   then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=r$.

Essentially this means that there are two functions that can basically outline your function, one from above ($f_+ (x)$) and one from below ($f_- (x)$) that you can use to determine a particular value of your original function, even if it initially doesn't seem like it exists.

In your problem, we can take a look at the graph of your function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & ,\ x \neq 0\\
0 & ,\ x=0 
\end{cases}$$
to see how this might work for us. (Graph pictured below, courtesy of Desmos).

[[image: Graph of the function <span class=]$f(x)$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fFT.png)

So as we can see, the graph squishes as we get closer to $0$ from either side of our function, but we can't determine what the tangent line is due to the limitations of $f(x)$. So using the Squeeze Theorem, we can take two new functions that "outline" our function in a sense.

So let us take $g(x) = x^2$ to be the "upper" function (the one labeled $f_+ (x)$ in our definition) and $h(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ to be the "lower" function (the one labeled $f_- (x)$ in our definition). We can find out using these functions whether we have a tangent at the origin or not. So let's graph these functions now alongside our initial function to see how this looks (We will let $g(x)$ be the blue curve and $h(x)$ be the green curve).

[image: Graph of f(x), g(x), and h(x)]

So as we can see, our functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ perfectly outline our function as it gets closer to the origin point. So our next goal is to find out the value of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ at the origin.

We can see (from these graphs especially) that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) = (0)^2 = 0$ and that although $h(0)$ is undefined, the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} h(x) = 0$ it is absolutely approaching $0$. Therefore by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$  at the origin. And thus, the Tangent line would be the line of $y = 0$, or in other words, the x-axis itself.

Hope this helped you out!

Comment: Although extensive and excellent in some ways this answer does not deal at all with the $\textbf{tangent}$ part of the question.  You have essentially answered what is the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, which also makes the function continuous.